# Unable to get the url redirected using requests library in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to crawl the data from a website. There is a url which redirects to another url when we hit it from a browser but when I try to do the same with python scripts it does not redirects as it supposed to be.
The first url is -
 http://www.marriott.com/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?propertyCode=ABZAP&isSearch=true&isRateCalendar=false&flexibleDateSearchRateDisplay=false&flexibleDateLowestRateMonth=&flexibleDateLowestRateDate=&fromDate=08/10/17&toDate=08/11/17&clusterCode=&corporateCode=&groupCode=&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfGuests=2&incentiveType_Number=&incentiveType=false&marriottRewardsNumber=&useRewardsPoints=false&numberOfChildren=0&childrenAges=&numberOfAdults=2

And it redirects to -
 http://www.marriott.com/reservation/rateListMenu.mi

I am also maintaining the session for cookies and also included the required headers.
Please look at the below code -

```
session.headers = ({
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
        'Host': 'www.marriott.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'http://www.marriott.com/search/findHotels.mi',
        'Accept': '*/*'})

    second_page ='http://www.marriott.com/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?propertyCode=ABZAP&isSearch=true&isRateCalendar=false&flexibleDateSearchRateDisplay=false&flexibleDateLowestRateMonth=&flexibleDateLowestRateDate=&fromDate=08/10/17&toDate=08/11/17&clusterCode=&corporateCode=&groupCode=&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfGuests=2&incentiveType_Number=&incentiveType=false&marriottRewardsNumber=&useRewardsPoints=false&numberOfChildren=0&childrenAges=&numberOfAdults=2'
    response = session.get(second_page, headers=session.headers)
    print(response.url)
```

When I am printing the url, it prints the original url and never gets redirected and when I try to print the first page's content it print this -

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head><script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/marriottCommon.js"> </script>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", function(a,b,c){
      window.location.reload()
    });
    xhttp.open('GET', '/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?istl_enable=true&istl_data', true);
    xhttp.send();
  </script>
</body>
```

Please tell me what am I missing here.

Comment: The first url does not redirect, at least me. It probably redirects you, because you have something in your cookies or local storage.

Comment: Yes it uses cookies. So I started from the home page in my browser.
http://www.marriott.com/default.mi
Then I filled random values which took me to the hotel list page and then I selected 1 of the hotels. This is that url. When I captured the session in fiddler I saw this first url getting redirected to the second one. Tried doing the same with python requests but no luck. Please help @newtover